# String.format("%f", value) - Rounding off end digits

Tags: java, math, floating-point, format, double

My value is `0.10565`

When this value get divided by 100 and formatted to string it gets converted to `0.001057`.

But my expected value is  `0.0010565` , there should be no rounding off happening at the end.

Is there any way to do it?

```
chargeAmount = Double.parseDouble(chargeInCents)/(double)100;
chargeInDollar = String.format("%f", chargeAmount);
```

It tried using this to convert my double value to string after dividing it by 100

Comment: They say you should use `BigDecimal` for amounts that need to be accurate.

Comment: From [the doumentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) *If the precision is not specified then the default value is 6.* This means that `%f` without specification of precision will print 6 decimals after the decimal separator and round as necessary, for example `0.001057`. There is a solution in the answer.

Comment: If you want 0.0010565 but don’t want redundant trailing zeroes, another solution is `new DecimalFormat("#####0.0#################").format(chargeAmount)`. This will print at least one decimal and up to 18 decimals if they are non-zero.

Comment: I seem to understand that the answer was deleted because of [GPT policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) (which I support).

Comment: Try `"%f"` --> `"%.7f"` to see a 7 decimal digit result.

Comment: I suspect OP is getting 0.001057 because math is done in a wider than `double` and the exact amount is like 0.001056500000000000000048741663....  When rounded to 6 places is 0.001057.

Comment: Rather than `double`, use decimal floating point types for money.